# How did my younger sister survive?

Tags: cipher, pattern, letters, password

In a far other universe, my little sister was trapped in a cave. Surprisingly for humans, in this universe, all caves are electronic. This electronic cave had nothing but 5 buttons, two little screens, one red and one blue, a numeric keypad, and the most brought to light, this little message:

#### Message

> Press the wrong button and that'll be your last action, press the
> right button and leave this cave.

#### Screens

The red little screen output the number `11`. The blue output  `19-8-7-10`.

#### Buttons

The five buttons had 5 different colors. My sister had always been an expert for colors (as well as having a PhD in colors (what a strange universe...)) and she could perfectly remember these:

1. Buff
2. Gold
3. Corn
4. Opal
5. Puce

### What my sister did

#### My favourite

To escape, my sister first pressed her favourite number into the numeric keypad: `2`.
Immediately, the blue screen started blinking. And 5 seconds after, it output the letter `y`. Simultaneously, the red little screen changed and output `10`. At that moment, she understood she had to write down on a little piece of paper she had: `11` and `19-8-7-10`.

#### That's not here for nothing

She then tried `19`, `8`, `7`, `10` but those four numbers didn't change the blue output and more stressful than anything, after that the red screen output `6`...

#### I was born the...

She tried `17` march `03` and thankfully the blue showed:

```
17: v
3: u
```

The red showed `4`...

#### Our cat was born the...

She tapped `25` november `11`...

```
25: s
11: p
```

Red..... `2`...

#### Father was born the...

She finally tried `29` november `77`

```
29: q
77: m
```

## How did she survive?

---

Alright, that's been four days that this puzzle is still unbreakable :p. Here is the first Hint I can give you:

#### Hint 1.a

> You probably found it, this puzzle is to find a certain $f$, which takes in input a number and returns one of the $26$  letters of the alphabet. This hint is to give some facts on $f$ and its link to this puzzle.
>
>  1. You also probably know that but the aim of this puzzle is to find $f(19)$, $f(8)$, $f(7)$ and $f(10)$.
>  2. $f$ is defined on any positive natural number, it is not defined on zero, it is not defined on negative numbers. It could be possible to define it by being treacherous but I haven't done it and that's not necessary for the puzzle. Plus there is no minus symbol in the numeric keypad !

#### Hint 1.b

> As it's defined on positive numbers, here is a list of its values:
>  $f(1) = p$
>  $f(2) = y$
>  $f(3) = u$
>  $f(4) = v$
>  $f(5) = k$
>  $f(6) = d$
>  $f(7) = ?$
>  $f(8) = ?$
>  $f(9) = w$
>  $f(10) = ?$
>  $f(11) = p$
>  $f(42) = e$

#### Please specify in your answer whether you solved the puzzle with or without hint 2.a and hint 2.b

#### Hint 2.a 7 July 19

> After being stuck for hours within this cave, my sister noticed that the ground was discreetly etched by the 26 letters of the alphabet. There was a mathematical symbol next to the 26 letters.

#### Hint 2.b 14 July 19

> The mathematical symbol is [$\%$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

#### Hint 3.a 17 July 19

> Actually modulo operation is used once or twice, or isn't used, to encrypt each number. Another important operator used within the encryption is $+$, it's systematically used once. The latter could also have been etched to the ground!

#### Hint 3.b 17 July 19

> Hint 2.a is as much important as Hint 2.b. The fact that the alphabet is etched is important.

Comment: hurts my head...

Comment: @ACoolGuy I added a hint ;)

Comment: This is similar to another puzzle I saw, in that rot13(gur erq ohggba ahzore qrpernfrf bar sbe rnpu cerff bs gur oyhr). It is therefore likely those values affect the f(x) equation.

Comment: @mkinson rot13(Vfa'g gung whfg n pbhagqbja fubjvat gur ahzore bs thrffrf yrsg? Bgurejvfr jr jbhyq abg or noyr gb pnyphyngr gur 4 erdhverq inyhrf, fheryl, fvapr gurl jbhyq abg unir n havdhr inyhr ohg engure qrcraq nygbtrgure ba gur erq vachg?)

Comment: @Stiv rot13(Lrf, vg'f n pbhagqbja.)

Comment: Guys, because the question is still unanswered and I want more attempts, I will give the bounty to the answer that gives the most information, no matter how small

Comment: Your hints didn't help but confuse me more, nevertheless good puzzle +1

Comment: Thank you! @Asterisk. About the hints, I think they could be very useful when rightly taken. Levieux who solved this puzzle first said they helped him. I agree that always depend on people, never possible to make hints helping everyone at a time ^^'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is:

> She pressed the **Gold** button.

How the transformation function works:

> Take the $n-th$ letter of the number $n$ when written out in English and shift this by $n$ positions. If a number consists of less than $n$ characters, restart from the beginning. If by shifting a letter by $n$ positions we reach the end of the alphabet, again, we restart from the beginning.
>
>  So for instance:
>  $1 >$ **O**NE $>$ **P** (O shifted by $1$ position)
>  $2 >$ T**W**O $>$ **Y** (W shifted by $2$ positions)
>  $3 >$ TH**R**EE $>$ **U** (R shifted by $3$ positions)
>  $4 >$ FOU**R** $>$ **V** (R shifted by $4$ positions)
>  $5 >$ **F**IVE $>$ **K** (F shifted by $5$ positions)
>
>  For numbers $19, 8, 7, 10$ we obtain:
>  $19 >$ NI**N**ETEEN $>$ **G** (N shifted by $19$ positions)
>  $8 >$ EI**G**HT $>$ **O** (G shifted by $8$ positions)
>  $7 >$ S**E**VEN $>$ **L** (E shifted by $7$ positions)
>  $10 >$ **T**EN $>$ **D** (T shifted by $10$ positions)
>
>  This leads us to the correct answer: **GOLD**, so the gold button must be pressed.

Quite challenging, but very nice puzzle!

**Previous answer below:**

Alright, nothing close to a solution yet, but I'll just post some of my observations here and maybe it helps someone else solve it:

> With the numeric keypad some input number may be supplied, which will then be transformed, via a function $f$, to one of the $26$ letters of the alphabet.
>  The blue screen shows the result of this transformation, once a number is supplied.
>  The red screen, as mentioned in the comments, is simply a countdown, showing the number of attempts left.
>  The five buttons are colored buff, gold, corn, opal and puce. The right button must be pressed to leave the cave.
>
>  Initially, the blue screen shows the numbers $19-7-8-10$. If these numbers are given as input, no result shows up on the blue screen, probably because this is the secret code we need to guess.
>  Since all the colors consist of four letters, the transformation on these four numbers probably leads to one of the five colors, i.e.: $f(19)-f(7)-f(8)-f(10) = b-u-f-f$ **OR** $c-o-r-n$ **OR** $g-o-l-d$ **OR** $o-p-a-l$ **OR** $p-u-c-e$
>
>  OP hinted that the transformation is somehow related to the mathematical modulo operation, which gives the remainder after division of two numbers.
>  OP further remarks that all mathematical symbols are pivoted by 45 degrees, meaning e.g. that **x** becomes **+** and vice versa, although it is unknown which, if any, of these operations are used in the transformation function.
>
>  Then there is the question of how a transformation on a number would lead to a letter. This might be where the modulo operation comes in: if $v$ is the numeric result of the function applied to the number $n$, then $v%26$ will lead to a number in the range $[0,25]$, which can easily be mapped to a letter, e.g. $a>0$, $b>1$, ... Unfortunately, this sheds no light on how to obtain this numeric result from the original input number...
>
>  Looking at the list of values as supplied by OP, we can see that both the number $1$ and the number $11$ are transformed into the letter $p$. Incidentally, this corresponds to the first letters of the $1st$ and $11th$ word of the message: "Press the wrong button and that'll be your last action, press the right button and leave this cave."
>  The only other double in the list is $f(4)=f(17)=v$, which may suggest that the initial sequence of $p, y, u, v$ is repeated, with $f(13)=y$ and $f(15)=u$. But since $f(19)$ would then have to yield $k$ we can see that this does not work, because none of the colors start with the letter $k$.

Comment: First two parts of your answer as well as last two are absolutely correct. Third part made me realized that my last hint may be misleading, thus I edited it accordingly, thank you! +1 for starting elucidating :)

Comment: Impressive ;p just in time to pocket the bounty as well! Congrats ;)

Comment: Thanks! Needed quite a lot of hints there, but finally the penny dropped ;)

Comment: :D I agree this puzzle is arduous before hint 2.a. Hint 3.b. strongly leads to the right way if it wasn't understood after hint 2 :). Was it your case?

Comment: Yeah, I think the alphabet hint gave me the last nudge in the right direction that I needed