# A world with roman numeral alphabet

Tags: cipher, pattern, letters

Tomorrow you will wake up and all the letters will be replaced by roman numbers. That'll be "ok" when you'll learn the replacement's order!

Nevertheless, today you have the possibility to make it a dream if you are able to translate `That won't happen` thanks the two following sentences:

```
XXIV-VI-III III-XI-IV-V-XVI?
Bye Earth?

XII-XIX-III-III-X II-III-XIX-XIX, XII-XIX-III-III-X V-VIII-XV-XVI-V!
Sleep well, sleep tight!
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the associations between letter and number given, the pattern is that

> numbers are assigned based on position on a QWERTY keyboard. E is `III` because it is the third character in the first row, R is `IV`, T is `V`, Y is `VI`, and so on.

So, `That won't happen` translates as:

> `VI-XVI-XI-VI II-IX-XXV-VI XVI-XI-X-X-III-XXV`

Comment: Wow, how can you get that so fast ;) I'll select you in 4 minutes when the website allows me to haha

Comment: Then I challenge you to a more difficult cryptography puzzle I've posted:
https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85341/how-did-my-littler-sister-survive ;p